# If everything is filled in form go to new page in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem, I want to make form and I want to check it with php script if it's filled. I found a solution, but Is there any other way(more 'professional') to make it. Here is my code now:

```
$x = 0;
    if(empty($name)){
    $nameKL = "No name";
    } else {
    $x = $x + 1;
    }

    if(empty($price)){
    $priceKL = "No price";
    } else {
    $x = $x + 1;
    }

    if($x == 2){
    header('Location: nextpage');
    }
```

So the Idea is: If checked variable is not empty I give `x=x+1` , If its empty I return error. I have two fields in form, so If `x==2` everything is okay. `else` errors are `echo'ed` in `html` form. So is there any smarter way to do this? I can't think out any on my own...

PS. It's only part of my code, and I need help only with this logical part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution on my own. I set up a variable that has a `true` value at the beginning and then:

```
$validate = true;

if(empty($name)){
$nameKL = "no name";
$validate = false;
}

if(empty($price)){
$priceKL = "no price";
$validate = false;
}


if($validate == true){
header('Location page.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of elements.

```
<input type="text" name="formadata['fname']" />
<input type="text" name="formadata['lname']" />
<input type="text" name="formadata['age']" />
```

in PHP you can loop all elements

```
$inputs = $_POST['formdata'];
$errors = array(
              'fname' => 'First name message',
              'lname' => 'Last name message',
              'age' => 'Age message',
          );
foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if(empty($input)) return $errors[$input];
}
```

So this way you can manage to check whether input is empty or not in PHP

Comment: `foreach` is not a good idea, because I have to return different errors each time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ternary Operation. Please check below simple code.

```
$x = 0;
$nameKL = empty($name) ? "No name" : $name;
$priceKL = empty($price) ? "No price" : $price;


if($nameKL && $priceKL){
header('Location: nextpage');
}
```

Comment: I want to know if there is a solution without increasing `x` value. Something with `true or false`

Answer (score 0):

```
$nameKL = empty($name) ? "No name" : $name;
$priceKL = empty($price) ? "No price" : $price;


if(empty($name) && empty($price)) {
    header('Location: nextpage');
}
```